# Infiniti Scroll com firebase e ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic, firebase

Pessoal estou aqui num aperto, estou usando o firebase v3.2.1 e to tentando implementar um infinity Scroll com ionic, a questão é que não sei como fazer, pesquisei no google e encontrei uma biblioteca firebaseUtils mais ela n é compativel com a nova versão do firebase. então agradeceria se me dessem um help, porque já estou a 3 dias que tento resolver isso. meu service ta desse jeito.

```js
angular.module('app').factory('artigoService', artigoService);
artigoService.$inject = ['$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray'];

function artigoService($firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

    var rootrEF = firebase.database().ref().child('constituicao');
    var object = $firebaseObject(rootrEF);
    var array = $firebaseArray(rootrEF);

    return {
        getArray: getArray,
        getObject: getObject,
        getAll: getAll,
        getByArtigo: getByArtigo
    }


    function getArray() {

        return array.$loaded();
    }

    function getObject() {

        return object.$loaded();
    }

    function getAll() {
        return object;
    }

    function getByArtigo() {

        var query = rootrEF.orderByChild("artigo").limitToLast(2);
        return $firebaseArray(query);


    }


}
```

Comment: Não sei ao certo, mas talvez você deva tentar tratar o firebase como se fosse um json qualquer, para entrar aplicar o conceito do `ion-infinite-scroll` - http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Comment: já tentei fazer isso, mas não funciona. podia fazer um exemplo só pra eu poder pegar a ideia

Answer (score -3):

O ionic podemos dizer que é o front do cordova, se vc for na página do IONIC vai encontrar seus CSS's use o  vai funcionar! ;)

Comment: ja resolvi, valeu pessoal.